# How to set variable as object refering to the current loaded userform without a loop?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, userform

Currently I make a code in a class module which work as expected :

```
Private Sub bt_Click()
Dim oObj As Object

If UserForms.Count = 0 Then
Set oObj = ActiveSheet
Else
For Each uf In VBA.UserForms: Set oObj = uf: Next uf
End If

Debug.Print oObj.Name

End Sub
```

If there's no UserForm seen in the active sheet, then the oObj is the activesheet - else the oObj is the only one Userform seen in the active sheet.

Curious if there is a syntax to set the oObj as the only one Userform seen in the active sheet without the loop, something like `set oObj = TheOnlyOneUserformSeenInThisPage` - I googled the internet and search this site, but I can't find the same question like mine.

What I've tried so far (by guessing) : `set oObj = UserForm(1)` but before the sub run it already throw me an error : *Sub or Function not defined* with the `UserForm` at `UserForm(1)` is highlighted in blue.

So my question is :
what is the syntax to set the oObj which something like `set oObj = TheOnlyOneUserformSeenInThisPage` ?

Any kind of response would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I believe `UserForms(0)` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Daniel, Never across my mind to also try just like your answer. Thank you very much.